# __str__ method in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder why the python magic method (**str**) always looking for the return statement rather  a    print method ?

```
class test:

   def __init__(self):
       print("constructor called")

   def __call__(self):
        print("callable")

   def __str__(self):
        return "string method"



  obj=test()  ## print constructor called


  obj()    ### print callable


  print(obj) ## print string method
```

my question is why i can't use something like this inside the **str** method

```
 def __str__(self):
        print("string method")
```

Comment: Have you ever done this: `a = str(obj); print(a)`?  Or this: `print("my object:", obj)`?  Try your `print` implementation on those examples and it should be obvious why you wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more to enable the conversion of an object into a `str` - your users don't necessary want all that stuff be printed into the terminal whenever they want to do something like

```
text = str(obj_instance)
```

They want `text` to contain the result, not printed out onto the terminal.

Doing it your way, the code would effectively be this

```
text = print(obj_instance)
```

Which is kind of nonsensical because the result of print isn't typically useful and `text` won't contain the stream of text that was passed into `str` type.

As you already commented (but since deleted), not providing the correct type for the return value will cause an exception to be raised, for example:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return None
... 
>>> str(C())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
>>>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if "casting" is the right word, but +1.

Comment: Thanks, conversion seems to be the more correct terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Because `__str__()` is used when you `print` the object, so the user is already calling `print` which needs the String that represent the Object - as a variable to pass back to the user's `print`

In the example you provided above, if `__str__` would print you would get:

```
print(obj)
```

translated into:

```
print(print("string method"))
```